# GAE error 204 - what does it mean how do I avoid it?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, cloud, app-engine-ndb

I am getting a blank screen with the following warning message in the logs:

```
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, 
causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for
the next request to your application. (Error code 204)
```

I am given nothing else to go on. I am making heavy use of tasklets (@ndb.tasklet), async datastore ops and async urlfetches (it is a search engine). According to appstats, I'm crunching, for example, 15min of processing time into 15sec. If I process less data it works. If I process more it fails with the above warning. The instances tab shows only once instance. My hunch is that I am overloading that instance.

I thought extra instances would automatically fire up to support the extra load - though maybe instances only respond to requests not CPU / memory load? When I fire up three different pages, three different instances also fire up. The problem is each request takes a lot of processing.

I could use a task queue to target a backend instance, but I would need to know when the task is completed and return the results. Unfortunately the task queue has [no way of monitoring when a given task has been completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504389/determine-if-a-task-has-been-deleted-gae-python).

How can I (and should I) explicitly split the processing across instances? Is there another solution? How do I avoid the 204 error message?

EDIT:
I had boosted my recursion limit with:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit
```

when I commented this out I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Where do you send the results. I understand that a task can send results over a channel to a javascript client.

Comment: Good point. Right now it is a simple response to a http request.

Comment: Are you using python or python27? If python27, do you have threadsafe set to true? If so, it's possible there's a threading issue with concurrent access in either your code, or NDB.

Comment: Yes: python27, threadsafe true. How do I go about debugging the threading issue with concurrent access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion limit makes me think that you are mixing synchronous operations with async ones.  Try to use just async ops and yield, not get_result(). Or show us some (real) code.

In particular, raising the recursion limit will eventually cause a C level stack overflow and that might well cause the process to be killed unceremoniously by the kernel. In that case the logs are also lost. Before you raised the recursion limit, what kind of stack trace did you get? Was it ~1000 entries, or only, say, a few dozen? If the latter, you're definitely running into the issue of mixing synchronous and async ops.

Note that there are two forms of synchronous ops, both to be avoided anywhere in a tasklet (and in anything it calls!): synchronous calls like ent.put(), key.get(); and async calls followed by a get_result() call, like ent.put_async().get_result().

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll go through and make such my asyncs are asyncs all the way down.